# opencsv: how to parse data with double quotes inside cells?

Tags: java, parsing, opencsv

I'm trying to parse some public data using [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) (version 3.10). Here's a snippet of code that grabs a CSV and maps the records to a list of POJO's:

```
URL permitsURL = new URL("http://assessor.boco.solutions/ASR_PublicDataFiles/Permits.csv");
InputStream permitInputStream = permitsURL.openStream();
Reader permitStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(permitInputStream);

CsvToBean<PermitRecord> csvToBean = new CsvToBean<PermitRecord>();

Map<String, String> columnMapping = new HashMap<String, String>();
columnMapping.put("strap", "strap");
columnMapping.put("issued_by", "issuedBy");
columnMapping.put("permit_num", "permitNum");
columnMapping.put("permit_category", "permitCategory");
columnMapping.put("issue_dt", "issueDt");
columnMapping.put("estimated_value", "estimatedValue");
columnMapping.put("description", "description");

HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<PermitRecord> strategy = new HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<PermitRecord>();
strategy.setType(PermitRecord.class);
strategy.setColumnMapping(columnMapping);

List<PermitRecord> permitRecordList = null;

CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(permitStreamReader);
permitRecordList = csvToBean.parse(strategy, csvReader);
```

There are fewer records in the parsed list than in the CSV. Looking at the data, I notice that there are sometimes double quotes within the cell values. Here's an example:

```
"R0601364                 ","LAFAYETTE","14-0486","DECK","4/29/2014 12:00:00 AM","3834","deck under 36\"""
"R0601365                 ","LAFAYETTE","13-0570","NEW CONSTRUCTION","5/22/2013 12:00:00 AM","121899","SIN FAMILY HOME PLN CUSTOM FIN BASEMENT"
```

The *deck under 36"* is causing the subsequent records to get rolled in to the description. This is more obvious when viewed through the IDE:

[image: permit record IDE screenshot]

Can you see what I'm doing wrong? I suspect there's an easy fix because it's parsed correctly by Excel, and opencsv seems to be the defacto standard for Java CSV parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Univocity CSV parsers](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers) are really easy to use. Mapping the CSV columns to POJO attributes is a breeze.

I added the following dependency to the `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.univocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>univocity-parsers</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
</dependency>
```

The CSV columns are mapped to attributes using annotations. Note the handy annotations:

- `Parsed(field = "abc")`: maps the CSV column to the variable
- `@Trim`: removes leading/trailing whitespace
- `@Format(formats = {"MM/dd/yyyy"})`: allows us to specify the date format

Here's the POJO:

```
package io.woolford.entity;

import com.univocity.parsers.annotations.Format;
import com.univocity.parsers.annotations.Parsed;
import com.univocity.parsers.annotations.Trim;
import java.util.Date;

public class PermitRecord {

    @Trim
    @Parsed(field = "strap")
    private String strap;

    @Parsed(field = "issued_by")
    private String issuedBy;

    @Parsed(field = "permit_num")
    private String permitNum;

    @Parsed(field = "permit_category")
    private String permitCategory;

    @Format(formats = {"MM/dd/yyyy"})
    @Parsed(field = "issue_dt")
    private Date issueDt;

    @Parsed(field = "estimated_value")
    private Integer estimatedValue;

    @Parsed(field = "description")
    private String description;

    // getters & setters removed for brevity
}
```

Then, to create a list of POJO's from the records in the CSV file:

```
URL permitsURL = new URL("http://assessor.boco.solutions/ASR_PublicDataFiles/Permits.csv");
InputStream permitInputStream = permitsURL.openStream();
List<PermitRecord> permitRecordList = new CsvRoutines().parseAll(PermitRecord.class, permitInputStream);
```

Credit to @JeronimoBackes for this elegant solution. And thanks for Univocity for their excellent CSV parser.

Comment: You can make your code shorter by using the `CsvRoutines` class: `List<PermitRecord> permitRecordList = new CsvRoutines().parseAll(PermitRecord.class, permitInputStream);`

Comment: Just one line to parse the stream! Wow, @JeronimoBackes. That's fantastic. Thank you.